# pandas dataframe conversion for linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

I read the CSV file and get a dataframe (name: data) that has a few columns, the first a few are in format numeric long(type:pandas.core.series.Series) and the last column(label) is a binary response variable string 'P(ass)'/'F(ail)'

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
label = data.ix[:, -1]
label[label == 'P'] = 1
label[label == 'F'] = 0

fea = data.ix[:, 0: -1]
logit = sm.Logit(label, fea)
result = logit.fit()
print result.summary()
```

Pandas throws me this error message: **"*ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data)*"**
Numpy,Pandas etc modules are imported already. I tried to convert fea columns to float but still does not go through. Could someone tell me how to correct?
Thanks

update:

```
data.info()
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 500 entries, 68135 to 3002
Data columns (total 8 columns):
TestQty         500 non-null int64
WaferSize       500 non-null int64
ChuckTemp       500 non-null int64
Notch           500 non-null int64
ORIGINALDIEX    500 non-null int64
ORIGINALDIEY    500 non-null int64
DUTNo           500 non-null int64
PassFail        500 non-null object
dtypes: int64(7), object(1)
memory usage: 35.2+ KB

data.sum()
TestQty            530
WaferSize         6000
ChuckTemp        41395
Notch           135000
ORIGINALDIEX     12810
ORIGINALDIEY      7885
DUTNo           271132
PassFail            20
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You need to convert the strings to int values I'm guessing, boolean may works also

Comment: Can you post some sample data that is causing the error?

Comment: @Alexander, the error was thrown after the line "logit = sm.Logit(label, fea)"

Comment: which implies there is an issue with label or fea, but only you can see this data which makes trouble shooting very difficult.

Comment: @EdChum, I did not quite catch your point. I did convert the last column to numeric value I suppose, 1 or 0.  Are you talking about something else?

Comment: So it is numeric? You stated it was binary Pass/Fail so I thought this was a string

Comment: @Alexander, so it is the inherent data that causes the problem, not my data type used in my code?

Comment: @EdChum, the label was numeric in the original dataframe. But I thought I already converted them into binary numeric one using my code above. I viewed it from object explorer window, it seems changed. This is not true?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your features be this:

```
fea = data.ix[:, 0:-1]
```

From you data, you see that PassFail sums to 20 before you convert 'P' to 1 and 'F' to zero.  I believe that is the source of your error.

To see what is in there, try:

```
data.PassFail.unique()
```

To verify that it totals to 500 (the number of rows in the DataFrame):

```
sum(label[label == 0]) + sum(label[label == 1)
```

Finally, try passing values to the function rather than Series and DataFrames:

```
logit = sm.Logit(label.values, fea.values)
```

Comment: same error message. BTW, you had a typo in your edit of my original post regarding this command.

Comment: try df.info() and df.sum() to get some basic diagnostics on your DataFrame.